# ¿Por que autoscroll de panel borra las lineas?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy ocupando generando lineas que enlazen las vertices de un arbol, pero no genera las lineas que estan fuera del rango del panel, a pesar de que tengo el autoscroll en "true", y cuando bajo para revisar las vertices, las lineas que estaban arriba desaparecen, este es el codigo

```
for (int ñ = 1; ñ <indice+bug; ñ++)//grega lineas
        {
            Pen myPen;
            myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            Graphics formGraphics;
            formGraphics = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, pos[ñ, 1] + 25, pos[ñ, 0], pos[cpila[ñ, 3], 1] + 25, pos[cpila[ñ, 3], 0]);
            myPen.Dispose();
            formGraphics.Dispose();



        }
```

Comment: La pregunta no está muy clara.Donde tienes ese codigo? Probablemente deberias ponerlo en el método `Paint()`del panel (creo que es donde intentas dibujar). P.D. `ñ` como indice? en serio? :)

Comment: ya no se me ocurrian variables, pero al fin de cuentas  una variable es una variable

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ejecutar el siguiente método, cuando se haga scroll:

```
private void panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta no está muy clara,pero sospecho que el problema es que estas tratando de dibujar en el panel en algun método externo, y lo que te está pasando es que al invalidarse el control obviamente se borra lo que dibujaste.

Lo que debes hacer es suscribirte al evento `Paint` del `Panel`y hacer algo así:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
     Pen myPen;
     myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
     for (int ñ = 1; ñ <indice+bug; ñ++)//grega lineas
     {

         e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, pos[ñ, 1] + 25, pos[ñ, 0], pos[cpila[ñ, 3], 1] + 25, pos[cpila[ñ, 3], 0]);
     }
     myPen.Dispose();
}
```

De todas maneras, si el panel tiene scroll dudo que te vaya a funcionar muy bien, ya que las posiciones en las que dibujas van a variar.